# Underscore in partial Sass file

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

Is it necessary to have a .scss partial file start with an underscore? The documentation states that a partial should start with an underscore, because the file would otherwise compile to a CSS file.

However I've noticed gulp-sass compiles files without an underscore into one complete CSS file just fine.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**1.** Partials must start with an underscore if you do not want them to be generated into a `css` file.

**2.** A `scss` file can import another file without an underscore and still compile correctly.

Take this example:

```
sass
    +-- base
    |   +-- _normalize.scss 
    +-- components  
    |   +-- site-header.scss
    +-- utilities       
    |   +-- _icons.scss
    +-- site.scss
```

Here we can see that `site-header.scss` and `site.scss` do not have underscores.  If I ran a gulp task to compile anything within the `sass` folder, two files would be output.

```
site-header.css
site.css
```

We do not want to generate `site-header.css` but because we have omitted the underscore the compiler only ignores files with an underscore and generates a `css` file for it.

`site-header.scss` can still be referenced in `site.scss` with an `@import`

```
@import 'components\site-header';
```

This will result in the same outcome whether it is prefixed with an underscore or not.

Comment: If you import a Sass file without a prepended underscore into another Sass file, that also is without a prepended underscore, then only one CSS file will be generated, so the claim `Partials must start with an underscore if you do not want them to be generated into a css file.` isn't really true - I can have partials that will not start with an underscore that would also not be generated into a CSS file. It depends on how you send your files to your compiler, right?