# Scss not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

So I have my navbar scss working perfectly fine but for some reason I cant get any scss to work on my posts. I have no clue why its not working. Here is some of my code.

Here is my _posts.html.erb

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4"> 
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-topper" style="background-image: url();"></div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
        <p class="published-date">Published Today</p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.description, length: 130) %></p>
        <%= link_to "Read", post, class: "btn btn-read" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im calling this in my posts index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
 <%=render @posts %>
</div>
```

This is my _posts.scss

```
.posts.index {
 .card {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #181818;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    .card-topper {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .card-block {
        padding: 10px;
        .btn-read {
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-radius: 0;
            color: black;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #d8d8d8;
            }
        }
        .card-title {
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
            a {
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
        .published-date {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            color: #787878;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-top: 0.3rem;
            margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
        }
        .card-text {
            font-size: 0.9rem;
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "navbar";
@import "posts";
```

Im importing the _posts.scss to my application.scsss just like I am with my _navbar.scss. Just dont understand why it seems to have no impact on my posts. Im using rails 5 and bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha3

Comment: what does your `application.scss` file look like

Comment: Nate Beers just updated to show the application.scss

Comment: Try removing the underscore on the filename, since it's not a partial ... `posts.scss`

Comment: @Jon I wonder why you say it is not partial. Can you inform me?

Comment: scss files are not partials.

Comment: @Jon Both .sass and .scss files can be partial. http://sass-lang.com/guide Also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/31319300/7565464. I would appreciate if you give some explicit resources to let me know more about your claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem is not with underscore. The problem is **.posts.index** and since you have no element with both **posts** and **index** rules, the style is not applied. Also, you miss a closing **div** tag in your _posts.html.erb file. you have three options:

**Option 1)** Change the _posts.html.erb file to something like this this (closing **div** is added):

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="posts index">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-topper" style="background-image: url();"></div>
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h4>
                <p class="published-date">Published Today</p>
                <p class="card-text"><%= truncate(post.description, length: 130) %></p>
                <%= link_to "Read", post, class: "btn btn-read" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Option 2)** Change index.html.erb to something like this (make sure you added closing **div** to _posts.html.erb):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="posts index">
        <%=render @posts %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Option 3)** Remove **.posts.index** from your _posts.scss file like following:

```
 .card {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #181818;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    .card-topper {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    }
    .card-block {
        padding: 10px;
        .btn-read {
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            font-weight: 300;
            border-radius: 0;
            color: black;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #d8d8d8;
            }
        }
        .card-title {
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
            a {
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
        .published-date {
            font-size: 0.8rem;
            color: #787878;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-top: 0.3rem;
            margin-bottom: 0.3rem;
        }
        .card-text {
            font-size: 0.9rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking away the "_" on my _posts.scss to make it just posts.scss ended up making it work just fine.

Comment: @D.Graves I tried your code with compass. It worked for me with underscore. May be it is different in ruby( I havent been around ruby)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** *Rename* `_posts.scss` to `posts.scss` *(remove **underscore**)*. (I prefer this way).

**Option 2:** *Change* `@import "posts";` to `@import "_posts";` *(add **underscore**)*.

I see `.posts.index { ....` in your `_posts.scss`, did you wrap your posts with these *class* some thing like this:

```
<div class="posts index">
  <div class="row">
    <%=render @posts %>
  </div>
</div>
```